# Checking which GitHub account your Ubuntu Machine (Windows) is linked to

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, windows-subsystem-for-linux, github-for-windows

Having trouble checking which GitHub account my Ubuntu Machine is linked to. I had made my first one last year, but the email it was attached to finally got filled up so I decided to switch emails, and made another account with it. I need a bit of help trying to figure out which GitHub account / user I am currently linked to.

I know how to link up my ssh keys, that's not as much of a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Click in files, open Home, then search for `.ssh` config (if it doesn't appear user ctrl + H)

Open your .pub file. At the end of secret, you will find the e-mail you attached to Github.

If you cannot remember, you can always delete this config and create another (since you haven't important repository in you account)